# How do I check a file size in memory before it is download

Tags: asp.net

I am currently working on a project where by I need to check the size of a file that is being downloaded from the website. I know that by default the file that is allocated is 4MB and I can change that in the web config file, the question is if the file size is greater than 4MB the system should display an error.  my page is like this

and the code behind look like this

```
private void btnExtract_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

 DataView dataView =  testReportData.WorktestItem.DefaultView;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
            f.Serialize(ms, testReportData);
            if (ms.Length < 4096)
            {
                this.ErrorLbl = Page.FindControl("ErrorLbl");
                ErrorLbl.Visible = true;
                ErrorLbl.Text = "error";


            }
}
```

any idea how can I solve this issue

Comment: Okay, so you have that code. What's not working about it? How is it not matching your expectations? Is there an error message?

Comment: upon testing to download a file greater than the expected size the error is not being displayed, the file just download

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if(ms.Length > 4096){//You error message}`?

Comment: I have put a debugging point but unfortunately, the debugging point is not being hit so there is no way for me to check the size of the file in memory

Comment: Good catch Izzy. Also, the this question says 4MB. The unit of ms.Length is in bytes. So that's actually `4,194,304` bytes, not 4096 (which is only 4KB).

Comment: Izzy! as you have mentioned I have a control where by a label has to display the error so ultimately the function within there looks fine to me and should work with my logic but for some reason is not

Comment: so mason what are you suggesting? replace the 4096 whit what?

Comment: @mason is right, replace `4096` to `4194304` and it should work just fine. And don't forget to change your if statement

Answer (score 1):

Your less than/greater than sign is backwards. You're only displaying an error if the file size is smaller than 4096 bytes. Also, your question says 4MB. The unit of ms.Length is bytes. So 4MB is actually 4,194,304 bytes. 4096 bytes is just 4KB. This should be the code:

```
private void btnExtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
     DataView dataView =  testReportData.WorktestItem.DefaultView;
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
     BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
     f.Serialize(ms, testReportData);
     if (ms.Length > 4194304)
     {
         this.ErrorLbl = Page.FindControl("ErrorLbl");
         ErrorLbl.Visible = true;
         ErrorLbl.Text = "error";
     }
}
```

You likely could have figured this out if you set a breakpoint on the first line of code, then stepped through the code line by line and compared how it executes with how you believed it should execute. When it differed, then you could check out the values to see why it executed differently. That's basic debugging skills, and it's absolutely critical that you learn how to do it in order to be successful. If Visual Studio is your IDE, then [Microsoft provides some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) for how to do this. I also recommend watching YouTube tutorials.